# Ubuntu 16.04 running GNOME3 randomly suspends

Tags: 16.04, gnome, suspend

My ubuntu 16.04 randomly is suspending after using it for a few days. I'm new to linux in general so I have no idea how to diagnose this problem and find out whats going wrong.

What usually happens is I am using my computer normally and then suddenly the screen goes black. I have to either press the power button or move the mouse a bit for the screen to back on. Then I login again (as if it was locked) and then I can use ubuntu again. But then it suspends again and becomes more and more frequence (sometimes every 30 seconds).

Comment: What happens when you disabled suspend?

Comment: I disabled suspend from the Settings > Power option but same thing happens. Also I'm trying to interpret the log but cannot understand it all.